# Luis Dialog Sample doesn't wait for user input

Tags: c#, botframework

so I'm trying to call a different dialog from my luis dialog. When I do this, I expect the luis dialog to wait until the other dialog has finished.

Since I cannot show you my real project, I've used the [Luis Dialog Sample](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/master/samples/Luis%20Dialog%20Sample) to reproduce my problem. I've added another step to the PromptWaterfallDialog which looks like this now:

```
public PromptWaterfallDialog()
        : base(nameof(PromptWaterfallDialog))
    {
        // This array defines how the Waterfall will execute.
        var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[] // 20190813 FPI diese Schritte werden jedes Mal ausgeführt wenn ein PromptWaterfallDialog aufgerufen wird
        {
            this.AskQuestionStepAsync,
            this.ReturnResultStepAsync,
            this.TestStepAsync
        };

        // Add named dialogs to the DialogSet. These names are saved in the dialog state.
        this.AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), waterfallSteps));
        this.AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));

        // The initial child Dialog to run.
        this.InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> AskQuestionStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var options = stepContext.Options as PromptDialogOptions;
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(options.Prompt) }, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ReturnResultStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Hi") }, cancellationToken);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> TestStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var options = stepContext.Options as PromptDialogOptions;
        options.Result = stepContext.Result as string;

        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("This is just a test"));

        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Complete, options));
    }
```

As you can see, I've added the TestStepAsync. I would expect the dialog to go like this:

1. Bot: PromptMessage (AskQuestionStepAsync)
2. User: some answer ...
3. Bot: Hi (ReturnResultStepAsync)
4. User: some input...
5. Bot: This is just a test (TestStepAsync)

But apparently, the bot skips waiting for the second user input and goes straight to the TestStepAsync as you can see here: [image: here]

Does anyone know if this kind of behavior is intented or not? And how do I get the bot to work like I expect it to do?

I'm using the Bot Emulator version 4.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Hi")

change it to:

Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Hi", InputHints.ExpectingInput);

Comment: Apparently the result stays the same

Comment: Hmm, I tried it on mine and it seems to work fine. Have you tried clean and rebuild solution. Also close VS and open again. Another thing you could try, I'm not sure if it's the problem but try adding another text prompt with a different name (and use it for second prompt):

this.AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
this.AddDialog(new TextPrompt("TextPrompt2"));

Comment: I've downloaded the whole sample again and just added the additional step. The result is exactly the same. What do you use to test it? I'm using the Bot Emulator version 4.6.0. I only get this behavior when calling a dialog from a LuisDialog. When I open a dialog with waterfall steps as my main dialog, the behavior like expected. That's the part I don't understand.

Comment: I'm using 4.6.0 as well. I just downloaded the sample and ran the Luis dialog. It works for me so unfortunately maybe it's an issue with the emulator, which others have had similar issues (wrong conversation paths). Probably not related but note that when debugging it retries if you pause too long (15seconds I think)

Comment: If you just want a luis bot template I used the Core bot (by going to New project, you may have to install the BotBuilder .vsix file to see it). It's a bit confusing at first but I just deleted the extra stuff and slowly built on top of MainDialog

Comment: I had a perfectly working bot already. Just for testing, I replaced my main dialog with a luis dialog and suddenly all my other dialogs behaved like described. On further investigation I've discovered that it happens in the Luis Dialog Sample as well. I've replaced the luis dialog with a component dialog and will use a LuisRecognizer for the luis handling. This seems to be working fine. Thank you for your time and help!
I will mark it as the answer, just in case others might want to try this work around too.